# The gateway is not working in Arduino EthernetENC

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, ethernet, networking, enc28j60

I am using ENC28J60 and EthernetENC library to connect an Arduino UNO with ATmega328 to the network. Everything works fine within the local network, but outside of it, I cannot ping the device. What could be the problem? The network settings are 100% correct (other devices work fine, and examples from the Ethernet library also respond to pings).

```
////////////////////////////////////// Settings //////////////////////////////////////
#define DHCP false          // true/false
#define CUSTOM_MAC true     // true/false

#if CUSTOM_MAC              // if true you can enter your custom mac address
#define MAC 0x00,0x5f,0x1C,0x05,0x5f,0x1C
#else
#define MAC 0x00,0x5f,0x1C  // Organizationally Unique Identifier (OUI)
#endif

#define IP_ADDRESS  192,168, 11,242
#define SUBNET      255,255,255,248
#define GATEWAY     192,168, 11,241
#define DNS         192,168, 11,241


// #define UIP_CONF_MAX_CONNECTIONS 0
///////////////////////////////////// Libraries //////////////////////////////////////
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <EthernetENC.h>  // Include the Ethernet library
#include <Agentuino.h>    // SNMP library
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <microDS18B20.h>
/////////////////////////////// Arduino sensor pins //////////////////////////////////
#define TEMPERATURE_1_PIN 0
#define TEMPERATURE_2_PIN 1
#define TEMPERATURE_3_PIN 2
#define TEMPERATURE_4_PIN 3
#define SENSOR_220V_PIN   4
#define SERVO_PIN         5
#define LED_ALERT_PIN     6
#if !SOUND_MUTE
#define SPEAKER_PIN       7
#else
#define SPEAKER_PIN       8
#endif
#define FLOOD_PIN         A0
#define DOOR_PIN          A1
#define GAS_PIN           A2


///////////////////////////// Ethernet / SNMP init ///////////////////////////////////
#if !DHCP
IPAddress ip(IP_ADDRESS);   // IP Address for arduino
IPAddress gateway(GATEWAY); // Gateway for arduino
IPAddress subnet(SUBNET);   // SubNet mask for arduino
IPAddress myDns(DNS);       // DNS for arduino
#endif

byte mac[] = {MAC};

//////////////////////////////////// My OIDs /////////////////////////////////////////
...
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////// function SNMP resived ////////////////////////////////
void pduReceived(){...}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup(){
  ///////////////////////////////// init pins ////////////////////////////////////
  pinMode(TEMPERATURE_1_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(TEMPERATURE_2_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(TEMPERATURE_3_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(TEMPERATURE_4_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(SENSOR_220V_PIN, INPUT);
  // pinMode(SERVO_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(FLOOD_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(DOOR_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(GAS_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_ALERT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  #if !SOUND_MUTE
  pinMode(SPEAKER_PIN, OUTPUT);
  #endif

  ////////////////////////////// init other //////////////////////////////////////
  Serial.begin(9600); // Serial monitor init
  Agentuino.begin();  // Begin Snmp agent on Ethernet shield

  ///////////////////////// Generate random mac address //////////////////////////
#if !CUSTOM_MAC
  if (EEPROM[0] == 255 && EEPROM[1] == 255 && EEPROM[2] == 255){
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++){
      randomSeed(analogRead(A5)); 
      mac[i] = random(0xFF);
      EEPROM.put(i - 3, mac[i]);
    }
  }
  else{
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++){ 
      EEPROM.get(i - 3, mac[i]); // Reed saved mac addres from EEPROM
    }
  }
#endif

#if DHCP
  Ethernet.begin(mac) // Initialize Ethernet Shield in DHCP mode
#else
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns ,gateway, subnet); // Initialize Ethernet Shield in static mode
#endif

///////////////////////////////////// Debug //////////////////////////////////////
Serial.println();
Serial.println();
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println(F("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :("));
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    delay(500);
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
  }

  Serial.print(F("localIP: "));
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  Serial.print(F("dnsServerIP: "));
  Serial.println(Ethernet.dnsServerIP());
  Serial.print(F("gatewayIP: "));
  Serial.println(Ethernet.gatewayIP());
  Serial.print(F("subnetMask: "));
  Serial.println(Ethernet.subnetMask());
  Serial.print(F("mac: "));
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    Serial.print(mac[i], HEX);
    if (i <= 4) Serial.print(F("."));
  }
  
  Serial.println();
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  Agentuino.onPduReceive(pduReceived);
  delay(10);
}


void loop(){
  Agentuino.listen();

  //////////////////////////////// Other code ////////////////////////////////////
  ...
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From outside your local network (i.e the internet) you can only ping the external IP address of your router, local IPs such as your 192.168.11.242 are not routable on the internet. Additionally many home routers are configured to not respond to external pings.
I see you're using snmp to communicate with your Arduino, you could forward the snmp port (normally port 161) from your router to the Arduino on 192.168.11.42:161 to achieve what you want but this is a security risk. You would then connect your snmp manager to your external IP address and your router would connect to your Arduino and do the required Network Address Translation to communicate. This assumes your router and internet provider allow port forwarding of the snmp port.

Comment: I am using a corporate network, not the internet, where I ping my device through a monitoring system. Many other devices work on the same principle in this corporate network. Therefore, all I need is for Arduino to properly route packets to the gateway.

Comment: I think this answer is correct.  You have to use the external ip address and perhaps set up port forwarding to your server.